# How php-fpm manages workers with dynamic process manager?

Tags: php, multithreading, nginx, high-load

I would like to clarify how php-fpm manages workers with *dynamic* process manager.

Let's assume we have following config:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 30
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 60
```

1. when php-fpm starts, it spawns 30 processes
2. there are no connections. Will the php-fpm shut down 10 workers according to *min_spare_servers* setting? If yes, after what time will it happen?
3. There are 40 connections to nginx. Will php-fpm serve each connection with separate worker, and immediately spawn additional workers to satisfy remaining connections?
4. There are 80 connections to nginx. How will php-fpm behave after it has launched 60 workers? The same as in (3)?
5. There are 120 connections to nginx. What happens after assigning 100 workers to 100 connections? Does php-fpm use some queue for the connections? Will it limit nginx? Will php-fpm start dropping connections with message "*server reached pm.max_children setting*"?

   6. There are 50 connections to nginx. Will nginx go back to 60 connections from 100? Or to 50? Will it immediately kill 40 workers or will it wait some time?

As you see, this is rather a generalized question about how php-fpm manages processes. More specifically, I would like to understand the difference between *pm.max_children* and *pm.max_spare_servers* in php-fpm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, let's assume that instead of nginx connection we speak about connection/request to upstream, that php-fpm serves.

> 2. there are no connections. Will the php-fpm shut down 10 workers according to min_spare_servers setting? If yes, after what time will it happen?

No, according to my test, master process does not terminate extra workers according to `min_spare_servers` number. Probably, it is good practice to specify `start_servers` equal to `min_spare_servers`.

> 3. There are 40 connections to nginx. Will php-fpm serve each connection with separate worker, and immediately spawn additional workers to satisfy remaining connections?

Correct, simultaneous connections to php-fpm will be served with separate worker. If number of requests is more than `start_servers` master process will fork additional workers (`fpm_children_make` call), up to `max_spare_servers`.

> 4. There are 80 connections to nginx. How will php-fpm behave after it has launched 60 workers? The same as in (3)?

It will fork as many workers as necessary to process all requests simultaneously, until it will reach `max_children` number; fpm master process performs maintenance every second (`fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance` call): if number of spawned workers are more than `max_spare_servers`, workers in idle state will send `SIGCHLD` signal to master process (`fpm_got_signal` and `fpm_children_bury` calls).

> 5. There are 120 connections to nginx. What happens after assigning 100 workers to 100 connections? Does php-fpm use some queue for the connections? Will it limit nginx? Will php-fpm start dropping connections with message "server reached pm.max_children setting"?

Correct, you will follow message in debug mode:

`seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers`

> 6. There are 50 connections to nginx. Will nginx go back to 60 connections from 100? Or to 50? Will it immediately kill 40 workers or will it wait some time?

All workers in idle state will be terminated, and master process will stop termination after number `max_spare_servers` is reached.
Parameters `min_spare_servers` and `max_spare_servers` are responsible for min and max numbers of workers that can be alive in idle state at the same time.

---

In order to understand dipper, try to turn on debug logging in `php-fpm.conf`:

`...
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm/fpm-daemon.log
...
log_level = debug
...`

Follow log file: `tail -f /var/log/php5-fpm/fpm-daemon.log` and use Apache benchmark tool `ab` to understand behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Could you clarify your answer to 5.? Mainly, will php-fpm queue connections, or just drop them?

Comment: Enabling status page you can get some data related to queue.
Parameter `listen queue len` defines how many maximum connection can be queued. This number gets defined in pool configuration - `listen.backlog` . Since php-fpm uses file/tcp sockets this number is limited with system variable which is defined in `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`

Comment: Forgot to mention, if queue gets full, upcoming requests will be refused.